# how can i write a code in C to display each letter of a word in both upper and lowercase?

Tags: c

i.e. user inputs NAME (all in capital) and the code will print out NnAaMmEe.

i want to use the function argv and args. this is the code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    int i;
    int count;
    char str [100];

    clrscr();

    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s", str);

    count = strlen(str);
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++){
        if((str[i] >= 97) && (str[i] <= 100)){
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
        for(i=0; i>=count; i++){
            if ((str[i] <97) && (str[i] >100)){
                str[i] = str[i] +32;                
            }
        }
        printf("%s", str);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`toupper()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/toupper.html) and [`tolower()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tolower.html) and define `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` if you want to use `arc` and `argv`.

Comment: Dare I suggest doing your own homework?

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incorrect in several ways:

- Since you want to use `argc` and `argv`, you need to add them as parameters of `main`, and remove the call of `scanf`
- You do not need nested loops for this - only one loop is sufficient
- If you take length of string with `strlen`, your loop should go from 0 to `len-1`, i.e. you should use `<` or `!=`, not `<=` in your loop condition
- You do not need to perform non-portable numeric manipulations on the characters; use `tolower` and `toupper` functions instead.
- Printing should be done character-by-character, not the whole string

The body of your loop should looks something like this:

```
char ch = ... // Get i-th character of argv[1]
printf("%c%c", tolower(ch), toupper(ch));
```

Print `\n` after the loop to flush the buffer:

```
printf("\n");
```

Comment: non-portable meaning to encodings other than ascii?

Comment: @AAA Yes, non-ASCII encodings use a different way of going from lower to upper case and back.

Comment: Minor point: `char ch = ... tolower(ch)` is UB should if `ch < 0` and not `EOF`.  C11 §7.4 1.  Certainly this is not the usual case and even then many `tolower()` gracefully handle it forcing -128 to -2 to 128 to 254. To be portable, do you think `tolower((unsigned char) ch)` (needed to prevent UB) is a practical necessity?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your program as below, You can obtain the output as you expected. The ascii range of capital letters is from 65 to 90 and for small letters it is 97 to 122.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
int i;
int count;
char str [100];

printf("Enter a string");
scanf("%s", str);

count = strlen(str);
for(i=0; i<=count; i++){
        printf("%c", str[i]);      
    if((str[i] >= 97) && (str[i] <= 122)){  
        str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
        if ((str[i] >= 65) && (str[i] <= 90)){
            str[i] = str[i] +32;
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
}
    getch();
}
```

Input  : `NAME`
Output : `NnAaMmEe`

Comment: Here I mean to say it will print the characters as he expected. thank you iharob, i edited the post for readability

Comment: Note what it says in [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toupper` and `tolower` functions for converting the values into lower and upper. Use another array to store that values.

In loop,

```
for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i < len ; i++) {
      if ( isupper ( str[ i]) ) {
           str1 [j++]= str [i] ;
           str1 [j++]=tolower(str[i]);
      }
      else if ( islower (str [i ] ) ) {
             str1[j++]= toupper (str[i]);
             str1[j++ ]= str [i]; 
      }
}
```

Then make sure that variables are declared.